# How will the test DB be re-generated from the development DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is an existing thread about this, but I'm still confused.

In the databasee.yml file:

```
Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
```

My development DB is on my local machine, and the test DB is on a cloud server. How would doing rake db:create and rake db:migrate on the test server erase and re-generate the test DB from the development DB?

Comment: The warning is very poorly worded. What actually happens is that in most typical test setups your test database is recreated from the schema when you run your tests to ensure a blank slate. How exactly this happens depends on your test setup. The warning is mostly just meant to be a warning that the data in your test db can (and should) be wiped regularily. The warning should probally be read as "don't be an idiot and use the same db for test, dev and production".

Comment: But if your Rails app can connect to your remote DB and has sufficient privledges it can absolutely wipe it.